# "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon of size '120x120' pixels

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

[image]I have uploaded several apps to the Appstore, but this time I am not able to get past this error. I have the right icon of the right size , right naming convention, checked the bundle identifier matching with the iTunes. What the heck am I missing then?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add icon 120*120 pixels, Simply

Answer (score 0):

you have to add 120x120 resolution icon in png format.
not in jpeg or other format.